# Jupyter-matplotlib: Error displaying widget: model not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm trying to install jupyter-matplotlib extension but can't make it work in a jupyterlab instance.
Once installed by following the steps here:
https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib
I get the error when executing a simple example:
*Error displaying widget: model not found*
[image: screen capture of described behaviour]

Here's the output of my `$ conda list` for relevant packages:

ipykernel                 5.1.1
ipympl                    0.2.1
ipython                   7.6.1
ipython_genutils          0.2.0
ipywidgets                7.5.0
jupyter_client            5.3.1
jupyter_core              4.4.0
jupyterlab                1.0.2
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0

Comment: Can you change the image to traceback  as text?

Answer (score 8):

Solved!
Turned out ipywidget 7.5 breaks jupyter lab and it isaffecting other libraries too.

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1659

downgrading to 7 solved the issue for me (allthough 7 wrt 7.5 should be backward compatibile)!

Also be sure to match ipympl 0.2.1 with jupyter-matplotlib 0.3.0 labextension.

`jupyter labextension install jupyter-matplotlib@0.3.0`

Comment: I am still getting the error with the ipywidgets version 7.6.3

Answer (score 8):

First you need to install:

```
 pip install ipywidgets

 conda install -c conda-forge ipympl
```

Then check if the following is OK:

```
!jupyter labextension list
```

You should see something like this:

```
JupyterLab v3.0.14
/home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/labextensions
    jupyter-leaflet v0.15.0 enabled OK
    jupyterlab-plotly v5.1.0 enabled OK
    @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
```

The most important part is here:

**Restart your jupyter notebook.**

Comment: The `labextension list` shows OK, but I still got the same error `Error displaying widget: model not found`.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error message when i first installed ipympl but it got solved automatically when I restarted the Jupyter lab.