# Ipympl outputs "Error displaying widget: model not found" when running Jupyter Lab in a pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pipenv

**OS**: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

**Installation:**

After running into [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2880) trying to use `pipenv install jupyterlab`, I install everything using `pip install` from within a fresh `pipenv shell` using `Python 3.8.0`.

```
pipenv shell
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy matplotlib jupyterlab ipympl
```

You can find the Jupyter Lab install doc [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html).

Running `pip list` outputs:

```
Package              Version
-------------------- ---------
anyio                3.5.0
argon2-cffi          21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings 21.2.0
asttokens            2.0.5
attrs                21.4.0
Babel                2.9.1
backcall             0.2.0
black                21.12b0
bleach               4.1.0
certifi              2021.10.8
cffi                 1.15.0
charset-normalizer   2.0.10
click                8.0.3
cycler               0.11.0
debugpy              1.5.1
decorator            5.1.1
defusedxml           0.7.1
entrypoints          0.3
executing            0.8.2
fonttools            4.28.5
idna                 3.3
importlib-resources  5.4.0
ipykernel            6.7.0
ipympl               0.8.7
ipython              8.0.1
ipython-genutils     0.2.0
ipywidgets           7.6.5
jedi                 0.18.1
Jinja2               3.0.3
json5                0.9.6
jsonschema           4.4.0
jupyter-client       7.1.1
jupyter-core         4.9.1
jupyter-server       1.13.3
jupyterlab           3.2.8
jupyterlab-pygments  0.1.2
jupyterlab-server    2.10.3
jupyterlab-widgets   1.0.2
kiwisolver           1.3.2
MarkupSafe           2.0.1
matplotlib           3.5.1
matplotlib-inline    0.1.3
mistune              0.8.4
mypy-extensions      0.4.3
nbclassic            0.3.5
nbclient             0.5.10
nbconvert            6.4.0
nbformat             5.1.3
nest-asyncio         1.5.4
notebook             6.4.7
numpy                1.22.1
packaging            21.3
pandocfilters        1.5.0
parso                0.8.3
pathspec             0.9.0
pexpect              4.8.0
pickleshare          0.7.5
Pillow               9.0.0
pip                  21.3.1
pkg_resources        0.0.0
platformdirs         2.4.1
prometheus-client    0.12.0
prompt-toolkit       3.0.24
ptyprocess           0.7.0
pure-eval            0.2.1
pycparser            2.21
Pygments             2.11.2
pyparsing            3.0.7
pyrsistent           0.18.1
python-dateutil      2.8.2
pytz                 2021.3
pyzmq                22.3.0
requests             2.27.1
Send2Trash           1.8.0
setuptools           60.5.0
six                  1.16.0
sniffio              1.2.0
stack-data           0.1.4
terminado            0.12.1
testpath             0.5.0
tomli                1.2.3
tornado              6.1
traitlets            5.1.1
typing_extensions    4.0.1
urllib3              1.26.8
wcwidth              0.2.5
webencodings         0.5.1
websocket-client     1.2.3
wheel                0.37.1
widgetsnbextension   3.5.2
zipp                 3.7.0
```

Notably `jupyterlab==3.2.8`, `matplotlib==3.5.1` and `ipympl==0.8.7` satisfy [the version lookup table](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl)

Now running `jupyter lab --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser` from inside the pipenv shell (`--ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser` because I'm accessing the notebook on a different machine).

Opening a new notebook with the default `Python 3 (ipykernel)` kernel, creating two cells

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import ipympl  # Confirming it is being found by the kernel
```

---

```
%matplotlib widget

# Example found from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149562/jupyterlab-interactive-plot

plt.figure()
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Running both cells gives me the common Error message:

```
Error displaying widget: model not found
```

What I've already tried:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028962/jupyter-matplotlib-error-displaying-widget-model-not-found)

Where I downgrade:

```
ipywidgets==7.0.0
ipympl==0.2.1
matplotlib==3.2.0
```

And install

```
jupyter labextension install jupyter-matplotlib@0.3.0
```

No change, same error.

---

Edit: Using Jupyter Notebook instead of of Jupyter Lab, which means `pip install jupyter` instead of `jupyterlab` fixes the issue.

Its what I'll do in lieu of an answer here, but would still like to know if anyone has a straightforward fix for Jupyter Lab.

Comment: dude you made my day! I keep getting "Error displaying widget: model not found" and googled for two whole days with no luck, this is the only solution that worked