# How to catch plotly "Error displaying widget: model not found"?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, ipython

I have jupyter notebook environments I want to test. Sometimes a plotly plot is not displayed, just an error message instead: "Error displaying widget: model not found". My problem is that this is no a valid error, you can not catch it with a try-except block, and you can not see the error in the `Out` or the `_` variables, because those just display the description of the model. So the issue probably lies within `IPython.display.display`.

What I want to do, is to catch this error, and modify the output of the cell (or the cell after) based on this. So not trying to fix the error, because I am trying to write tests.

Here you can see a sample code that results in `Error displaying widget: model not found`.

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
from IPython.display import display

class ClickableScatterPlotly:
    def __init__(self, data):

        self.scatter_fig = go.FigureWidget(
            [
                go.Scatter(x=data[:,0], y=data[:,1], mode='markers', showlegend=False),
            ]
        )

        self.scatter = self.scatter_fig.data[0]

        self.scatter.on_click(self.clicked)
        self.select_point(0)
        self.ui = self.scatter_fig

    def clicked(self, trace, points, selector):
        self.select_point(points.point_inds[0])

    def select_point(self, i):
        n = len(self.scatter.x)

        c = ['blue'] * n

        c[i] = 'red'

        with self.scatter_fig.batch_update():
            self.scatter.marker.color = c

data = np.random.rand(50,2)

click_scatter_plotly = ClickableScatterPlotly(data)
display(click_scatter_plotly.ui)
```

Comment: Not so sure if this might give you a pointer: SO answer around [issue 3558](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73733358/20107918), and [Jupyter-matplotlib: Error displaying widget: model not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57031292/20107918)